# Cache Line Format/Layout

Tags: caching, layout, cpu

I would like to understand the layout of a cache line (not cache layout) and was searching for more in depth explanation or a figure on which fields are contained in a cache line, preferably for Intel CPUs.

On Computer systems: a programmer's perspective from Randal E. Bryant; David R. O'Hallaron it is stated that:

> A cache line is a container in a cache that stores a block, as well as other information such as the valid
>   bit and the tag bits.

However, this is very generic and does not state if there are other bits as well.
I was searching the web, aforementioned book and the Intel manuals, but didn't find anything else. The only thing that seems to be readily available is information about the layout of the cache and page table entries.

Is this any undisclosed information or is it just too trivial and the only fields available in a cache line are data block, valid bit and tag bits (as stated in the book)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the data itself, each cache line will typically have coherence metadata (not just validity, using four-state MESI is a popular coherence tracking method) and either parity or ECC metadata.

For each set (or sometimes for each line), there will also be replacement information. Not Recently Used can be implemented with a bit per line that is set on use and cleared when all use bits are set in a cache set. Tree-based pseudo-Least Recently Used has a binary tree for each set where each bit indicates if its half of the group was more recently used.

An L2 or L3 cache that is used by more than one L1 may have metadata about which L1 caches hold the data to avoid having to send invalidation or sharing update requests to all the L1s.

Other metadata may be present to improve replacement beyond the basic method (e.g., EvictMe bits have been proposed), to indicate compressed status, to provide prefetch hints, etc. AMD's Athlon stole ECC bits to store branch information in L2 (only providing parity protection for instruction memory).

Instruction caches can also predecode cache lines to make decode simpler and faster. This can alter the encoding (e.g., replacing a branch target offset with the branch target inset (the sum of offset and the offset)), rearrange fields for more regular encoding, or pad the instruction with instruction type information.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! That really helps me! Do you, by chance, have some further reference or source you could point me to?